# Is it possible to get the path where files sent from forms are saved in go?

Tags: go

I am having a problem when I want to work with files sent to a web server in golang, the first thing I do is have all the files sent, with the following code:

```
r.ParseMultipartForm(0)

files := r.MultipartForm.File

for file := range files {
    file, header, error := r.FormFile(file)

    if error != nil {
      log.Print(error)
    }
}
```

The `r` variable is the value of `*http.Request`. So far I think so far everything is going well. But, according to [the official documentation of `ParseMultipartForm`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseMultipartForm):

> The whole request body is parsed and up to a total of maxMemory bytes
> of its file parts are stored in memory, with the remainder stored on
> disk in temporary files.

In other words, the files are saved on the server. Is it possible to obtain the path where they are saved? I don't think copying the files is a good idea because that would take up twice as much disk space for each request. Am I missing something? Or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Just to clarify, I would like to get the path where they are saved ( for example: `"/tmp/file.jpg"`). I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: If your goal is to store uploaded files to the server's file system, then create a [multipart.Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#Reader) on the request body, iterate through the parts,  and copy directly from the part to a file.   See the Reader's [formData](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.1:src/mime/multipart/formdata.go) method for an example of how to iterate through the parts.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, this is incorrect:

> I don't think copying the files is a good idea because that would take up twice as much disk space for each request.

Note the word "temporary" in your quoted documentation. Any temporary files that may exist will be deleted unless you *do* copy them someplace permanent.

Regarding getting their paths, you can't do this, and you don't need to. Note the rest of your quoted documentation:

> The whole request body is parsed and up to a total of maxMemory bytes of its file parts are stored in memory

For many files, there **is no file on disk**. The file only lives in memory. It's only the stuff that doesn't fit in memory that ends up in one (or more) temporary files. Those files are useless to you, they are an implementation detail that you cannot depend on.

Your are meant to use the provided file handle and `FileHeader` object returned by [`FormFile`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.FormFile) to interact with the uploaded file.

Comment: But, if I put the value that is saved in memory to be `0`, it would all be files, right?